# Can mach_wait_until() get interrupted by a signal?

Tags: macos, signals

`sleep()` may work up earlier than specified because it can be woken up by a signal.

man page states:

> The sleep() function suspends execution of the calling thread until either seconds seconds have elapsed **or a signal is delivered to the thread** and its action is to invoke a signal-catching function or to terminate the thread or process.

There is no man page for `mach_wait_until()`. Can it also be interrupted by a signal? On an old Apple mailing list post someone claimed it won't but I ran into a situation that would only make sense if it does. Is that documented anywhere or does anyone have more insights on this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it can.

Of course there is no documentation, it's not the Apple way to write a documentation.

But fortunatelly, we can check it with apple opensource xnu kernel:
https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-7195.81.3/

I would say we are interesting in the file xnu-7195.50.7.100.1\osfmk\kern\clock.c
There is a trap that implements mach_wait_until with such call:

```
wresult = assert_wait_deadline_with_leeway((event_t)mach_wait_until_trap, THREAD_ABORTSAFE,
    TIMEOUT_URGENCY_USER_NORMAL, deadline, 0);
```

The THREAD_ABORTSAFE here is declared in xnu-7195.50.7.100.1\osfmk\kern\kern_types.h with some useful comments:

```
* THREAD_ABORTSAFE:
 *    Wait will end if someone explicitly wakes up the thread, the wait timeout
 *    expires, the current thread is being terminated, if any signal arrives for
 *    the task, or thread_abort_safely() is called on the thread.
 *
 *    Using this value means that you are willing to be interrupted in the face
 *    of any user signal, and safely rewind the thread back to the user/kernel
 *    boundary.  Many syscalls will try to restart the operation they were performing
 *    after the signal has been handled.
 *
 *    You must provide this value for any unbounded wait - otherwise you will
 *    pend user signals forever.
```